# How can i retrive the value of a XML Parameter Entities?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

if i want to declare a XML Parameter Entity:

```
<!ENTITY % author "William Shakespeare">
```

How can i get the value of that entity?

For example:

With the following code, i get a "Entity not defined" [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK35z.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE DTD [
   <!ENTITY % author "William Shakespeare">
]>
<sgml>&author;</sgml>
```

With the following code, Chrome return literally  %author; and not William Shakespeare [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGW25.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE DTD [
   <!ENTITY % author "William Shakespeare">
]>
<sgml>%author;</sgml>
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can only reference a parameter entity within a DTD (internal or external subset).

Per [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-prolog-dtd)...

> Parameter entity references are recognized anywhere in the DTD
> (internal and external subsets and external parameter entities).

There are also restrictions when using parameter entities in the internal subset. See the spec linked above for more details.

This is what your XML should look like:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE sgml [
   <!ENTITY author "William Shakespeare">
]>
<sgml>&author;</sgml>
```

Comment: I need to use a Parameter Entity, not a General Entity

Comment: @Zefiro38 - You can only reference a parameter entity in a DTD. What you're asking is not possible.

Comment: You don't need to use a parameter entity for what you are trying to achieve. They exist for a quite different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Change your XML to

```
<!DOCTYPE sgml [
   <!ENTITY author "William Shakespeare">
]>
<sgml>&author;</sgml>
```

So, remove the `%` from the entity reference.

Comment: Changing "<!DOCTYPE DTD [" into "<!DOCTYPE sgml [" i have always the same errors.